# telerik table stop displayed properly after I start using windows 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was developing project in Windows 7 using VS for Web 2013 and SQL Server R2 every thing was fine. Then I change operation system to Windows 8.1 Pro. After that I run my project and all the tables stop displaying properly in browsers(Chrome, Mozila, Internet Explorer). It just look like 1 line of data, with check box.

Does any one knows what is missing? plagins, drivers?

Comment: Did you upgrade an Win 7 machine to Win 8.1, or have you transferred a project to a machine running 8.1?  If transferred, I would suspect you did not really transfer everything correctly, I would suspect that there may be a compatibility issue. You really should specify exact version of Telerik control, e.g., RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX and Version # -- Since this is an enviormental issue, you will find that it will likely be very difficult for someone else to debug.

Comment: Also you may find it more efficient to contact Telerik than kill yourself debugging without outside assistance. If you still have access to the old environment, tools like DotNet decompilers (including the free one from Telerik) can be very useful indeed.

Comment: I upgrade my PC to Win 8.1

Comment: I personally don't care what you did in the sense that I can't debug an environmental problem. The fact you upgraded means that I would first check if everything I was using was supposed to be compatible with Win 8.1 -- I the answer is yes, it is also very useful to try a clean install on Win 8.1 instead of and upgrade

Comment: Thank you for your respond but issue not in Win 8.1 installing process!

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall Telerik.  It's obvious the upgrade process broke something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason for that issue were in VS 2013! I solve it by adding just one LINE

```
<add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

link that helped http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2013/10/23/messy-html-and-js-errors-when-you-install-visual-studio-2013.aspx